# Integral $\int_{0}^{1} x^2 e^{-2\pi i k x}\,dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to figure out the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^2 e^{-2\pi i k x}\,dx$$

but cannot get the correct result which should be

$$\frac{-1}{2\pi i k} + \frac{1}{2(\pi k)^2}$$

Here is what I have:

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^2 e^{-2\pi i k x}\,dx$$

Integration by parts:

$$f'(x) = e^{-2\pi i k x}, f(x) = \frac{e^{-2\pi i k x}}{-2\pi i k},$$

$$g(x) = x^2, g'(x) = 2x$$

$$\left[\frac{e^{-2\pi i k x}}{-2\pi i k} \cdot x^2\right]_0^1 - \int_{0}^{1} 2x \cdot \frac{e^{-2\pi i k x}}{-2\pi i k}\,dx$$

$$\left[\frac{e^{-2\pi i k}}{-2\pi i k}- \frac{1}{-2\pi i k}\right] + \frac{1}{\pi i k} \int_{0}^{1} e^{-2\pi i k x} \cdot x\,dx$$

Using integration by parts again

$$f'(x) = e^{-2\pi i k x}, f(x) = \frac{e^{-2\pi i k x}}{-2\pi i k},$$

$$g(x) = x, g'(x) = 1$$

$$\left[\frac{e^{-2\pi i k}}{-2\pi i k}+ \frac{1}{2\pi i k}\right] + \frac{1}{\pi i k} \left( \left[\frac{e^{-2\pi i k x}}{-2\pi i k} \cdot x\right]_0^1 - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-2\pi i k x}}{-2\pi i k}\cdot 1\,dx \right)$$

$$\left[\frac{e^{-2\pi i k}}{-2\pi i k}+ \frac{1}{2\pi i k}\right] + \frac{1}{\pi i k} \left( \frac{e^{-2\pi i k}}{-2\pi i k} + \frac{1}{2\pi i k} \left[\frac{e^{-2\pi i k}}{-2\pi i k} + \frac{1}{2\pi i k} \right] \right)$$

$$\frac{e^{-2\pi i k}}{-2\pi i k}+ \frac{1}{2\pi i k} + \frac{1}{\pi i k} \left(\frac{e^{-2\pi i k}}{-2\pi i k} - \frac{e^{-2\pi i k}}{4\pi^2 i^2 k^2} + \frac{1}{4\pi^2 i^2 k^2}\right)$$

using $e^{-2 \pi i k} = 1$ and $i^2 = -1$

$$\frac{1}{-2\pi i k} + \frac{1}{2\pi i k} + \frac{1}{\pi i k} \left(\frac{1}{-2 \pi i k} + \frac{1}{4\pi^2k^2} - \frac{1}{4\pi^2k^2} \right) $$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi^2 k^2}$$

I hope I did not make too many notational mistakes and included enough steps.

Comment: When you first integrate by parts, for the left term, don't forget that there is a $x^2$ factor.

Comment: Furthermore, what is $\cos(2k\pi)$ and $\sin(2k\pi)$?

Comment: I suppose that $k$ is a non-zero integer, in which case $e^{2\pi i k}=1$ for any $k\in\mathbb Z$ will simplify your expression considerably, and give you the right answer.

Comment: Don't forget $i^2 = -1$ when simplifying your expression.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to integrate
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} x^2 e^{-2\pi i k x}dx
=&\ \frac{d^2}{da^2}\left(\int_0^1 e^{-ax}dx\right)_{a=2\pi ik}
=\frac{d^2}{da^2}\left(\frac{1-e^{-a}}a\right)_{a=2\pi ik}\\
=&\ \left[\frac{2(1-e^{-a})}{a^3} -e^{-a}\left(\frac2{a^2}+\frac1a\right)\right]_{a=2\pi ik}=\frac{1}{2\pi^2k^2}- \frac{1}{2\pi i k} 
\end{align}
where $e^{-2\pi i k }=1 $ is recognized.